# Setting a file in APMediaPlayer

Tags: android, processing

I am trying to add sound to an app I am creating in processing. Currently everything works, but when I try to add sound through APMediaPlayer, it crashes. Specifically, it crashes when I try to set a file to an instance of the class using .setMediaFile(FileName)

Here is my code for testing:

```
import apwidgets.*;

APMediaPlayer player; 

void setup() {
  player = new APMediaPlayer(this); //create new APMediaPlayer
  player.setMediaFile("scoreSound.mp3"); //set the file (file is in data folder)
  player.setLooping(true); //restart playback end reached
  player.start(); //start play back
}
void draw() {
  background(0); //set black background
  fill(255);
  textSize(24);
  text(player.getDuration(), 50, 100); //display the duration of the sound
  text(player.getCurrentPosition(), 10, 30); //display how far the sound has played
}
```

It runs if I comment out the call to player.setMediaFile(), but doesn't play any audio (which makes it useless).

Comment: How exactly does it crash? Do you see an error of some kind?

Comment: The specific point of error is in line 81 of the APMediaPlayer class.